# how to echo data json from ajax to modal js codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i want to display data from ajax into model show with echo php, i have made ajax and have working no errors.

this is my model

```
public function detail($id_branch) {
    $this->db->select('TR_BRANCH.*');
    $this->db->from('TR_BRANCH');
    $this->db->where('BRANCH_ID', $id_branch);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

my controller

```
Public function detail($id_branch){
    $data = $this->main_model->detail($id_branch);
    echo json_encode($data);
    $this->load->view('template/pages/home_index', $data);
}
```

my ajax

```
function coba(id_branch) {
    $('#placeholder').hide();

    $('#placeholder').show(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>home/detail/" + id_branch,
            success(res){
                // alert(id_branch)
            }
        })


    });

}
```

my view

```
<div id="placeholder">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
         <p><?php echo $data->DISPLAY_NAME; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if i

```
<?php echo $data->DISPLAY_NAME; ?>
```

in my modal, i'm getting error like Undefined variable: data. result data json_encode already appear in network based id_branch. how to fix it? pls help

Comment: Why are you doing `echo json_encode($data);` then `$this->load->view('template/pages/home_index', $data);` and are you meaning to return the view to ajax? Provide a `print_r($data)` *before* `echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting DISPLAY_NAME in Ajax request, so you cannot use $data->DISPLAY_NAME,

You need to give id to p tag & update its value in ajax success method

```
<p id="displayName"></p>


success(res) 
{
    // alert(id_branch)
     $("#displayName").html(Read Value from res data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

View receives `$data` keys (and their value) as pieces, not whole the `$data` variable.

So, in your "my view", it should be `echo $DISPLAY_NAME;`.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return the view to ajax, and that you only want to get one record. Do the following:

```
public function detail($id_branch) {
    $this->db->select('TR_BRANCH.*');
    $this->db->from('TR_BRANCH');
    $this->db->where('BRANCH_ID', $id_branch);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();

}
```

Controller:

```
public function detail($id_branch){
    $data = $this->main_model->detail($id_branch);
    //echo json_encode($data); // why??
    $this->load->view('template/pages/home_index', $data);
}
```